# Retrieve data based on condition oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have the following question:
I would like to display all users who have similar names to a specified user.
To do this, I first fetched the data of the specified user and store them in page items.

In the second step, I have created a classic report and would like to list all users here who have a similar name.

How can I say that, for example, only the beginning of the value of this page item must be the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If "similarity" means "match first several letters", then you'd

```
select ...
from table_of_users u
where substr(:P1_USER_NAME, 1, 3) = substr(u.user_name, 1, 3)  --> match first 3 letters
```

---

However, maybe you'd want to consider another approach and use `UTL_MATCH` package. For example (cross (self) join of Scott's `EMP` table):

```
SQL>   SELECT a.ename,
  2           b.ename,
  3           UTL_MATCH.jaro_winkler_similarity (a.ename, b.ename) similarity
  4      FROM emp a CROSS JOIN emp b
  5  ORDER BY similarity DESC
  6  /

ENAME      ENAME      SIMILARITY
---------- ---------- ----------
SMITH      SMITH             100
MILLER     MILLER            100
ALLEN      ALLEN             100
FORD       FORD              100
JAMES      JAMES             100
<snip>
JAMES      JONES              76
JONES      JAMES              76
JAMES      ADAMS              73
CLARK      BLAKE              73
BLAKE      CLARK              73
<snip>
SCOTT      MARTIN             45
JAMES      MARTIN             41
MARTIN     JAMES              41
TURNER     ALLEN              41
ALLEN      TURNER             41
FORD       JAMES               0
FORD       MILLER              0
MILLER     WARD                0
MILLER     SCOTT               0
<snip>
```

In your example, that would be e.g.

```
select ...
from table_of_users u
where utl_match.jaro_winkler_similarity(:P1_USER_NAME, u.user_name) > 80; -- match more than 80%
```